# Connecting to server TCP in C

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

I need to clarify something. I'm making a server/client TCP program in C.

What happens if a client tries to connect (using connect()) when the server is not stuck in accept()? I mean, when it's busy? What does connect() return?

EDIT:

I'm on Linux environment.

```
if (connect(...) < 0) {
    // ERROR AND LEAVE
}
```

This is what I'm doing in my client. From what I've read and learned, if the server is busy and not accepting, connect() should wait a little bit, and then return -1, if the server is still busy. Is that right?

If so, how do I avoid that "little bit"? I want it to return -1 right away.

Comment: Check out the manual for `connect(2)` that should give you all the information you need about what `connect` returns and the error values it sets in `errno`.

Comment: according to [`the connect documentation`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/connect), the return value indicate whether the connection is successful or not

Comment: On linux: Connect normally blocks until the connection is established or after some non further specified timeout has passed. In the latter case it returns -1 and `errno` is set accordingly. You can change this default behavior my making the socket non-blocking, but that's another story.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you mind checking out my edit? @mrksngl

Comment: "A little bit" is, as I said, not further specified. I think it depends on some system wide parameters. Also if -1 is returned, it doesn't mean that the server is busy. It might also be not available or something else happened. You have to look in the manpage for possible errors, like others suggested. I also said that you can change the behavior, but even then: you do not really like to return "immediately": you must give the server (or better: the whole network system) some time to actually establish the connection.

Answer (score 1):

> From what I've read and learned, if the server is busy and not accepting, connect() should wait a little bit, and then return -1, if the server is still busy. Is that right?

The acceptance of the TCP connection, i.e. the TCP handshake, is fully done in the OS kernel independent from a call to `accept`. `accept` just returns already accepted connections to user space. Thus, even if the server is currently busy the connection will succeed as long as there is still space in the pending queue. The size of the pending queue is set with `listen`. If the pending queue is full since the application did not retrieve accepted connections from it for some time but clients still connected, then the server OS will reject the connect attempt, i.e. `connect` will fail.